# Can't create migrations with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create migrations for my pet project.
However, I'm experiencing an Error that can't google an answer for:
it says:

```
`vincent@master-PC:/media/vincent/82944C77944C6FA9/Users/Ghost/Desktop/Python/PB/lesson 40/meeting_planner$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/vincent/82944C77944C6FA9/Users/Ghost/Desktop/Python/PB/lesson 40/meeting_planner/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/vincent/82944C77944C6FA9/Users/Ghost/Desktop/Python/PB/lesson 40/meeting_planner/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vincent/.local/share/virtualenvs/lesson_40-49hQCJIK/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vincent/.local/share/virtualenvs/lesson_40-49hQCJIK/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/vincent/.local/share/virtualenvs/lesson_40-49hQCJIK/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/vincent/.local/share/virtualenvs/lesson_40-49hQCJIK/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/vincent/.local/share/virtualenvs/lesson_40-49hQCJIK/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.cont enttypes'
```

P.S. I'm using SQLite database

I DID define my app in the settings correctly (checked it twice), tried to restart my VScode and restart pipenv too. However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
django.contrib.cont enttypes
```

should be

```
django.contrib.contenttypes
```

Comment: Numerous thanks, sir. It's my first question here and you answer was as helpful as quick!